# How to set up timeout to connection using socket class in java?

Tags: java, sockets

Socket: Connect spends 2 minutes looking for IP before it timesOut. I want to reduce that time to 10-15 seconds.

For connection I am using following code....

```
public static boolean available (String host, String port){
    try {
          Socket s = new Socket (host, port);
          return true;
       }
    catch (Exception e) {
       return false;
    }
}
```

How do I minimize timeout time to 10-15 seconds instead of 2 minutes?
Is there any method to do that or any other alternate way?

Comment: @Neel If you know it then only answer.....

Answer (score 2):

You don't set a timeout for the socket, you set a timeout for the operations you perform on that socket.

For example `socket.connect(otherAddress, timeout)`

Or `socket.setSoTimeout(timeout)` for setting a timeout on read() operations.

See: http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html